# Magento Newsletter queue not populating with recipients

Tags: magento, message, newsletter, magento-1.8

I am trying to send a newsletter through my Magento 1.8 CE store.  I create the template and then queue it and set the date/time for the queue. When I click "Save Newsletter", it thinks for a while, then the screen goes blank (white with no messages etc). On going back to the queue to see what is happening, it is doing everything as normal except the no of processed and recipients is zero. I have 12000 subscribers.

I have tested this in my test site and the newsletters get sent out as expected without any problems.

Any suggestions?

---

As suggested, I have had a look in the exception log and found this.

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Magestore_Magenotification_Block_Adminhtml_Notification_Window' in /home/explimco/public_html/sub/on/store/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /home/explimco/public_html/sub/on/store/includes/src/__default.php(27644): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /home/explimco/public_html/sub/on/store/includes/src/__default.php(27586): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('adminhtml/notif...', Array)
#2 /home/explimco/public_html/sub/on/store/includes/src/__default.php(27621): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/notif...', 'notification_wi...')
#3 /home/explimco/public_html/sub/on/store/includes/src/__default.php(27388): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/notif...', 'notification_wi...')
#4 /home/explimco/public_html/sub/on/store/includes/src/__default.php(27354): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/explimco/public_html/sub/on/store/includes/src/__default.php(27359): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/explimco/public_html/sub/on/store/includes/src/__default.php(13798): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /home/explimco/public_html/sub/on/store/includes/src/__default.php(13723): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /home/explimco/public_html/sub/on/store/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#9 /home/explimco/public_html/sub/on/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php(88): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#10 /home/explimco/public_html/sub/on/store/includes/src/__default.php(13872): Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController->gridAction()
#11 /home/explimco/public_html/sub/on/store/includes/src/__default.php(18234): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('grid')
#12 /home/explimco/public_html/sub/on/store/includes/src/__default.php(17768): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /home/explimco/public_html/sub/on/store/includes/src/__default.php(20368): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /home/explimco/public_html/sub/on/store/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /home/explimco/public_html/sub/on/store/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a "white screen of death" that could indicate a PHP error.

After you save it won't send until after the queue date happens.  So is the problem actually when you save it?

- Check var/log/exception.log - see if there are any messages in there that could indicate a problem. If so edit your original question and paste it in so we can see.

Is this on a remote or local server?  If remote, have you set up the chron file  (http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/58791/)?  Were you able to send out an email without the newsletter (in other words, is email working in general)?

Comment: Thanks Gisto. I have posted the log as suggested.

It is on a remote server and runs with a cron job. Other emails are working fine. The test site sends the newsletter without issue and the live site used to also send out newsletters without issue.

Comment: Looking at that logfile it looks like there's an issue with your Magestore Magenotification module.  Could you disable it and see what happens?  Also you mention that you used to be able to send newsletters out - did you install Magestore and then start having issues?  Is there another extension that you installed and then noticed issues?